# Train's tractive force graph how to analyze it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

From [Wikipedia's tractive force article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractive_force) in the graph:

[image: Tractive force]

if train is moving 90 km/h does it mean that a ~85 kN force neeeds to be applied on it continuously to balance the friction and other dissipative forces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diagram assumes that the train can produce a constant power of $7$MW. The power is related to the force and velocity by:

$$ P = Fv \tag{1} $$

so if the power is constant then a graph of force against velocity will be a hyerbola, and that's what the figure you mention shows (it isn't explained why the segment $A$ to $B$ is flat).

Given a constant power $P = 7 \times 10^6$ W and a speed of $90$ m/s equation (1) tells us that the force is $77.\dot{7}$ kN. This isn't too far from your estimate given that the graph is only a rough one.

However note that the graph does not tell us whether the train was accelerating or at constant speed at $90$ m/s, so we cannot tell if this $78$kN force is greater than the drag or not. If the rain has reached constant speed then the drag force is indeed equal to the $78$ kN tractive force. If the train is still accelerating then the drag is less than $78$ kN.

Comment: Thanks very much for helping me. I didn't notice that the power after B point was constant. How can I get energy spent to reach certain speed? If it was power by time I could calculate, how about in this case that is force by speed?

Comment: @pb772: the problem is that the graph tells us nothing about the time so we don't know the acceleration. Given that the power is constant the energy used is just the constant power times the time taken, but without knowing the time taken (or alternatively total distance moved) there is no way to do the calculation.

Comment: In a similar case I have the previous graph, plus the electric current delivered to the motors by speed graph (motors are electric) can I calculate energy from these two graphs?

Comment: @pb772: still no I'm afraid. You need to know how long the electrical current is delivered for to know the total power.